# When should I require a user to re-login to their account?

Tags: login

I am building a service for developers and I am wondering when I should "expire" a session. I obviously don't want my users to have to login every time they reload the page but I wouldn't want them to have to only login once and have complete access to their account forever either.

I have decided on "every 24h" and I wanted to see what the community has to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon the easiest way to figure this out is to ask developers who are using your service. No need to guess. Get the data first, then you can decide.

Comment: Alright, I'll just do that. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to expire the user login after a limited constant time period, then you can use cookie with expire value, in node express server.

```
res.cookie('rememberme', '1', { expires: new Date(Date.now() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)), httpOnly: true });
```

Else you can use session storage if you want to logout the user whenever he closes the current browser.

Comment: UX.stackexchange is about user experience and not about implementation. The question of the OP was WHEN a user should be required to re-login to their account.

Comment: Thanks Arif but as Nash explained, I wanted to know how long until the session token expires.